# Корректно ли встраивать QML виджеты в проекты на QWidget?

Tags: qt5, c++11, qml, qwidget

У меня есть обычный Qt проект на QWidget. Слышал про то, что QML виджеты не слишком хорошо дружат с уже написанным приложением на QWidget. Есть ли какие-то подтверждения этого? В чём может быть сложность?

Answer (score 0):

QML это отдельный движок для отрисовки UI-компонент со своим интерпретатором JavaScript и JIT-компиляцией, в то время как виджеты это С++-обёртки над платформозависимым кодом для отрисовки UI.

Если необходимо отрисовать в своём проекте QML компонент, то в модуле есть класс `QQuickWidget`, который под капотом создаёт свой инстанс движка. Конечно же это накладывает свои ограничения и уменьшение производительности, о чем можно почитать в [доке](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qquickwidget.html).